# lodash.js partial application on function.apply

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js, lodash

Given the following function, the usage of `_.partial` function throws an error:

```
function foo(x, y) { return 1 + 2; }
p = _.partial(foo.apply, null);
p([1,2]);
```

I get:

> TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on [object Window], which is a object and     not a function

What am I doing incorrectly here? Is there another way to achieve what I'm doing?

Comment: you don't use any arguments, so there's no point in use apply or currying in general.

Comment: This works: _.partial(foo)(1, 2), foo and foo.apply are two different functions.

Comment: @erdeszt The whole point is to pass the arguments (besides the first) as an array, that is why I have to use foo.apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i belive this what you're going for:

```
function foo(x, y) { return x + y; }
p = Function.apply.bind(foo, null);
p([1,2]); // ===3
```

the closest i can get underscore to do is via _.bind:

```
function foo(x, y) { return x + y; }
p = _.bind(foo.apply, foo, 0);
p([1,2]); // ===3
```

you may also want to consider another flexible use of that function, to sum a whole array of more than 2 elements:

```
 function foo(x, y) { return x + y; }
_.reduce([1,2,3,4,5], foo); // == 15
```

or using vanillaJS:

```
function foo(x, y) { return x + y; }
[1,2,3,4,5].reduce(foo); // == 15
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but any idea why _.partial generates an error?

Comment: In regards to your edits, what I'm actually doing is this:
    
    _(xs)
    .zip(ys)
    .zip(zs)
    .map(Function.apply.bind(foo, null));

Answer (score 3):

At the risk of misunderstanding the issue here, I wanted to share a tactic I just stumbled upon for a similar situation.

#### Problem:

The problem, in my case, is that sometimes I need to call a function (`foo`) with some arguments without changing the `this` context.  Unfortunately, the list of arguments is not deterministic-- sometimes there might be 2, sometimes there might be 3, etc.  And since `_.partial` expects each argument to be passed in as a separate argument, I was initially stumped.  For example:

```
// some dynamic array of args
var args = [new Error(), [{id: 3}, {id: 7}], function cb() {}];

// the function we want the partially applied to
var fn = function foo ( /* ...want `args` in here... */ ) {
  // ..implementation...
}

// can't do it with normal _.partial() usage...
// var newFn = _.partial(fn, args[0], args[1], ... args[args.length])
```

#### Solution:

This is much the same use case when you'd want to use `apply` instead of `call` to invoke a function normally.  So after putzing around w/ it for a while, I realized I could just do:

```
var argsToLodashPartialFn = [foo].concat(args);
var newFn = _.partial.apply(null, argsToLodashPartialFn);
```

#### tldr;

Or, more concisely:

```
var newFn = partialApply(foo, args);

// === newFn(args[0], args[1], ...., args[n])
newFn();
```

And here's the implementation as a reusable function:

```
/**
 * partialApply()
 *
 * Like `_.partial(fn, arg0, arg1, ..., argN)`,
 * but for a dynamic array of arguments:
 *
 * @param {Function} fn
 * @param {Array}    args
 * @return {Function}
 */

function partialApply (fn, args) {
  return _.partial.apply(null, [fn].concat(args));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of lodash 3.2, you would use the [spread()](https://lodash.com/docs#spread) function for this:

```
function foo(x, y) { return x + y; }
var p = _.spread(foo);
p([ 1, 2 ]); // → 3
```